# Is CUBE function is unusable from MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner to MySQL, and I'm trying to learn Transact-SQL.

I know `ROLLUP()` is changed to WITH ROLLUP, but I can't find it for `CUBE()`.

How can I use `CUBE()` for MySQL 8.0?

This is a query that I'm trying to run

```
SELECT order_dt, count(*) as CNT
    FROM starbucks_order
GROUP BY CUBE(order_dt, order_item)
ORDER BY order_dt;
```

Comment: CUBE? I am not aware of cube,Do you have a reference for this? BTW mysql and transact sql are not the same and it's not always possible to use the same code on both. If you want to learn transaction sql install sql server..

Comment: @P.Salmon CUBE exists and it is not T-SQL specific. [Cube](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#cube) "CUBE extension will generate subtotals for all combinations of the dimensions specified". Using GROUPING SETS syntax for 3 columns a,b,c it would be equivalent of `((), (a), (b), (c), (a,b), (a,c), (b,c), (a,b,c))`

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda Show me where you find it in mysql manual..

Comment: @P.Salmon OP asked very specific question how to **emulate** this in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by a few columns, you can use UNION SELECT.

In case of 2 columns: Combination of (1,2) and (2,1)

```
SELECT
    order_dt, order_item, count(*) as CNT 
FROM starbucks_order 
GROUP BY order_dt, order_item WITH ROLLUP
UNION 
SELECT
    order_dt, order_item, count(*) as CNT 
FROM starbucks_order 
GROUP BY order_item, order_dt WITH ROLLUP;
```

In case of 3 columns: Combination of (1,2,3), (2,3,NULL) and (3,1,NULL)

```
SELECT
    order_dt, order_item, order_id, count(*) as CNT 
FROM starbucks_order 
GROUP BY order_dt, order_item, order_id WITH ROLLUP
UNION 
SELECT
    NULL, order_item, order_id, count(*) as CNT 
FROM starbucks_order 
GROUP BY order_item, order_id WITH ROLLUP
UNION 
SELECT
    order_dt, NULL, order_id, count(*) as CNT 
FROM starbucks_order 
GROUP BY order_id, order_dt WITH ROLLUP;
```